# Python subprocess.Popen - adding GCC flags results in "no input files" error

Tags: python, gcc, subprocess, popen

I'm building a Python script to automate my build process, which invokes GCC using subprocess.Popen.  My initial attempt works fine.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = Popen(['gcc', 'hello.c'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
>>> p.wait()
0
>>> p.communicate()
('', None)
```

However, once I pass additional options to GCC I get the error "no input files", as demonstrated below:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = Popen(['gcc', '-o hello hello.c'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
>>> p.wait()
1
>>> p.communicate()
('gcc: no input files\r\n', None)
```

Any ideas what may be causing this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shouldn't that be

```
p = Popen(['gcc', '-o', 'hello', 'hello.c'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```